# Run Qt Quick (EGLFS) on Raspbian lite?

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install Qt on a Raspberry Pi 2 and 3, fresh with Raspbian lite, following all kind of (official and unofficial) guides and scripts. But it seems impossible.

I have a RPi 7' official display, and I want to run a simple Qt Quick binary using -platform EGLFS.

Is there an easy way to install Qt with EGLFS plugin to run applications? Without having to cross-compile or build from source.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a build of Qt is available in the raspbian repo. Not sure if it includes the eglfs plugin.
As an alternative I provided builds of Qt for Pi2: https://bugfreeblog.duckdns.org/2016/07/binaries-for-pot-540-beta1-on-qt-570.html. You can use those. Eglfs is included. You can find indications on how to use here: https://bugfreeblog.duckdns.org/using-pot-builds.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where do I have to move the Qt-rasp2-5.7.0 folder?